# MySQL localhost: "connection refused"

Tags: mysql, connection

sorry for this post that it might be repeated, but I could not quite figure out from the other posts still.

I am unable to log on mysql localhost database, and the server is down says mysql@localhost:3366 - Refusing Connections. In mysql workbench start/shutdown mysql server, it is saying the database server instance is unknown (with start server button grayed out) and refreshing the status doesn't help.
Also, the mysql server should always be running automatically in the background whenever PC is restarted, but it is not showing in the services now.

when I try to execute mysqld from cmd, it just shuts down the server. And responds with 
-"The Innodb memory heap is disabled"
-"the system tablespace must be writeable" 
-"InnoDB init function returned error" 
-"InnoDB registration as a storage engine failed"

Anybody has a solution to this? Thanks much!

Comment: Are you in a Linux based OS??...did you try to restart mysql??

Comment: @RobertRozas I am running on windows 8.1 OS, and yeah I have several times already to run the mysql notifier for mysql server.

Comment: If you're getting 'connection refused' to the localhost, there is nothing listening at the target port. It isn't correct to say that MySQL refused the connection. TCP refused the connection. MYSQL isn't even there.

Comment: Mysql has a connection limit...maybe that limit as been reached...try to stop the service and run it again or try to kill the process...or try rebooting the OS

Comment: I don't think that's my problem, I cant even find the service running under admin tools -> services. I think it's unable to be launched or like what @EJP was saying with TCP refused connection. Not exactly sure how to enable that.

Answer (score 0):

Install it. Re-install it, if you're convinced it was already installed. The fact that it isn't even listed in the services suggests otherwise however. If it was installed but wouldn't start it would still show up, but not as started.